# How to add external sensor data to pictures, canon DSLR, hot shoe, electronics

Tags: electrical-engineering, computer-engineering, computer-hardware, consumer-electronics, electronics

Here's a challenge -

I am trying to add different sensors data (height,temperature,distance by laser) to pictures i take with a canon DSLR camera.

Would it be possible to connect different sensors through a canon DSLR "hot shoe" or other camera input?
and then add the sensor information to the picture at the precise moment the picture was taken?

for example - have a temperature sensor connected to the camera, and add the temperature data to the image stored in the camera.
same way other data that comes with taken pictures such as geo location,shutter info, etc..

i need it to be VERY precise timing wise - exactly on the time the picture was taken.

would love to hear your ideas,
Also looking for someone who can do this as paid project.

Macgyver

Comment: Probably not as you would need to customize the cameras’ firmware which you don’t have access to. Better would be to tether the camera and sensors to a computer.

Comment: Canon camera firmware is not impossible to access. See https://magiclantern.fm/

Comment: "*I am trying to add different sensors data ...*" Do you mean *sensor's* or *sensors'* maybe? Punctuation matters. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. The basic hot shoe just presents a short circuit to the flash to trigger it. How will that help you?

Comment: You're right, i mean sensor's data.
In need to capture value from the sensor, and know what the value is exactly when the picture was taken. The hot shoe starts the flash EXACTLY when the picture is taken, so I thought it would be possible to hack it somehow in order to add a value from a sensor to the picture data, and EXACTLY when the picture is taken. Im open to any other idea

Comment: No, you can't capture the data **exactly** when the photo is taken. There must be some finite time for the sensor values to be read. What do you **really** need?

Comment: Elliot, the camera is attached to a vehicle that drives around 70-80 Mph, and is taking thousands of pictures. The sensor's speed is enough to be considered real time,
Its measured in mili seconds. Other time sync systems have been tried and are not accurate Enough
And cause other issues. Once a picture is taken, the sensor should write its value (distance by a laser for example) to the image data that is on the camera. Would need some firmware hack i guess. It is a challenge. Any ideas?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The hot shoe contacts often closes before the capture of the image so that there is some time for the flash intensity to reach a maximum. Or you can delay the image (by having the light travel a long path relative to the measurement signal) and then you can capture data exactly when the photo is taken!

Comment: @DDuck You say "often closes before" or "some time" which doesn't sound very exact to me. So all we have to do is make sure that the subject is appropriately distant from the camera so that the speed of light syncs things up? Sorry, but this is not reasonable.

Comment: In the past, flashes consisted of a bulb in a housing, electrically linked to a contact on the camera's shutter. The bulbs themselves had different ratings in terms of reaching peak illumination and this rating was governed by a letter or series of letters such as M (Medium) - 25 ms;  F (Fast) - 5 ms; X (Instant) and FP (Flat Peak). If the measurement takes, say, 5 ms we set the camera to M flash and have the hot shoe trigger a monostable with a delay of 20 ms, which then triggers the the measurement - 5 ms _before camera exposure starts_ and essentially simultaneous with the exposure.

Comment: @DDuck Now "exactly" has become "essentially simultaneous". We are making progress. Now put some numbers on "essentially"...is 5.001ms before OK? is 6ms OK? **Engineers need numbers**.

Comment: The temporal alignment is much better than the integration time of the exposure.

Comment: @Macgyver - Serious question, why does it need to be written to the EXIF data at the point of capture? It's easy to edit the EXIF data after the fact, so if you can store the sensor data on a separate memory, and then write a simple script or batch process to add the sensor data to the photos? As long as there are the same number of sensor readings as there are photos, you wouldn't necessarily even need to timestamp them (although clearly that's safer). I'm imagining a setup where the flash signal triggers a data log via an interrupt pin? How does that sound?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Exactly! You should put this into an answer. Just log the data and post process the image EXIF data.

Comment: @EricShain - I wanted to check if there was a specific reason that this had been ruled out before spending time writing out a full answer! It almost seems too obvious to have not been thought of already?